# I need to match and/or merge 3 different lists that have corresponding information. A and B, C and D, E and F

Tags: excel, list

I think I have a difficult one for you. How do I take 3 different lists of data and either match the title and info in rows or merge the information to compare? If I can get the lists C & D and E & F to match rows from A & B that would work very well also (Example 1 below).

- List 1 is A and B which has 9000 cells, List 2 is C and D which has 8000 cells, and List 3 is E and F which has 6000.
- I need to compare by merging the 3 lists or by getting each Title which is in A, C, E to be listed in matching rows. Columns A, C, and E would match down the column along with their corresponding terms from B, D, F column. Basically A=B, C=D, and E=F, they should always be next to each other as the second column is corresponding information.

-Many of the terms in A, C, and E will match but not all of them especially because they have different quantities. For example, list 1 & 3 may be missing but list 2 is not. List 2 would be the only information available. Some information from B, D, and F will match but some may not but I still need it included. (See screenshot for example.)

- Any information missing from a cell should be left blank. The examples below show missing data from lists. The reason for that is because the term is most likely not included in the specific list.

These are examples of the end goal for which ever method can be accomplished.

Example 1. Match by row and columns. Empty column for E shows that list did not include the title term therefore it had no corresponding term in F. But the rows are still in line for comparison for the others to match.

[Example 1 of spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cslq2.png)

Example 2. Merge titles and Match Terms. Columns on the left (A-F) calculate results in later columns.

[Example 2 spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T16XU.png)

Example 3. Match Titles, Delete Duplicates from A, C, E and Merge Terms B, D, F. Or G and H if they merge right in spreadsheet.

[Example 3 spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C8Q1.png)

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines perhaps:

```
=LET(x,SORT(VSTACK(<List1>,<List2>,<List3>)),y,UNIQUE(TAKE(x,,1)),HSTACK(y,MAP(y,LAMBDA(z,TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(DROP(x,,1),TAKE(x,,1)=z))))))
```

Or:

```
=LET(x,SORT(WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A1:E9000,1),2),y,UNIQUE(TAKE(x,,1)),HSTACK(y,MAP(y,LAMBDA(z,TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(DROP(x,,1),TAKE(x,,1)=z))))))
```

I had no markdown sample data to work with, but theoretically this would comma-seperate your list-options per title.

Comment: First one works like a charm! Second is missing ) I think before ,y,UNIQUE(TAKE.... part but even with that something is not right.

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to use this. The number of rows in each list is as follows. Are you able to use these values to show me how it is done?
9291, 8312, 6254